# ASP.NET - Como tener siempre en los FormWebs la información dependiendo un correo que ponga en el login

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema es la carga de información de un usuario.

Lo que deseo hacer es que al ingresar un correo y clave en el login se almacene en algún lado ese correo sin borrarse.
Cuando el usuario es valido lo envió a su perfil donde se encuentra numero,correo,área, nombres y apellidos lo pase por una variable y me funciona depende el correo trae los datos en la base de datos y los muestra en el perfil pero al cargar nuevamente todo se borra ya que la variable pasa a ser un string = "" vacio.
Como puedo hacer que esto no pase cuando visito varias web dentro de un mismo sistema no se si tal vez debo hacer el uso de las cookies pero nunca las e usado.
Quien me pueda dar una guía muchas gracias.
MI código es así.

```
txtEmail.Text = Request.Params["email"];

        foreach (DataRow dtr in perfil.MyInfo(txtEmail.Text).Rows)
        {
            txtID.Text = dtr["ID_Usuario"].ToString();
            txtNombres.Text = dtr["Nombres"].ToString();
            txtApellidos.Text = dtr["Apellidos"].ToString();
            txtDoc.Text = dtr["Documento"].ToString();
            txtRol.Text = dtr["Rol"].ToString();
            txtArea.Text = dtr["Area"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Almacena el dato en variables de "Session" Session["email"]=Request.Params["email"]

Comment: Ok ya lo hice pero aun asi se me sigue borrando.
Me voy a otro formweb y vuelvo al perfil con el botón asignado ya no me vuelve aparecer la información de perfil vuelve y me sale en null la variable session. Ya que con esta variable me trae los datos de la base de datos no se como hacer que siempre este ese correo en esa variable session para ir a hacer la consulta a la db

Comment: Entonces probá con cache, para insertar hace lo siguiente "Cache.Insert("Mycache", Request.Params["email"],null,datetime.now.addSeconds(30),timeSpan.zero)" al datetime de expiración podes configurar la que vos quieras de esa forma lo almacenas y para obtener el valor "var email= Cache["MyCache"]" espero te sirva saludos.